# Unreliable search box when looking for users on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, meta

This is a minor issue but a bit annoying: The [list of users page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users) on meta was recently modified.

Since that change was effectuated, the search option's behavior is somewhat erratic:

While users [Rajesh D](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/2987/rajesh-d) and [Michael Lugo](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/173/michael-lugo) do have meta accounts, the search field [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users) is unable to find them:

[image: Exhibit A]

[image: Exhibit B]

but sometimes it *does* find something:

[image: Exhibit C]

This is probably not intended behavior and it would be nice to fix that.

Comment: While I'm at it: would it be possible to allow the display on the users page sorted by total reputation again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The participation tab only included users that were active in the last 60 days.

Michael stopped participating on meta a while back so is no longer included in the list.

I just amended it so it includes all users, but the participating ones show up first.

Comment: Yes, but this does not address my complaint: If I look for a user name then I want to find that user no matter what the circumstances are and in particular I don't care much whether that user participated in the last 60 days or not. The default search should look for *all* users, not some group that is automatically selected for me whether I want that or not. There's no way I can convince the search to find Rajesh D for me and this behavior is highly inconvenient.

Comment: I follow, I will see if I can add all the "non participating" users at the bottom

Comment: Great, thanks in advance for trying!

Comment: @Sam I agree with t.b. I too was puzzled why the search seemed to behave so strangely. If it can't be changed, then at least it would be helpful to state prominently on the search page that it only searches users active in the last nn days, so that users are not misled about the scope of the search results.

Comment: yes ... just fixed it @BillDubuque